# Google first click free visit count

Tags: google-search

I am trying to implement Google first click on my website. Unfortunately there are not much documentation and examples around it. There is a very breif article, which is talking about counting number of user visits to be "**a minimum of 5 articles per day**".

https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?hl=en-GB

My confusion is:

- Is google going to handle the number of visits?
- Am I suppose to do it with cookies for example? what if the user drop the cookie?

Please guide to any code example you may know.

Comment: I found a documentation talking about implementing Flash LSO cookies rather than normal cookies which are harder to remove. I'm still not convinced. I'm sure technical savvy people can remove them easily. here is the doc: http://www.slideshare.net/indraneel8/first-click-free

Comment: Also I don't assume flash LSO - flash shared objects work in IOS devices?!